# Defering execution including a success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

I need to rewrite some javascript code that has some synchronization problems. I'm using jquery 1.7 and making a call to a method called GenerateData() that calls $.ajax with success and fail callbacks.

GenerateData() calls a webservice to retrieve a list of records that get passed to the success callback which in turn generates and xml data file on disk. When the call is successfull, the xml file is merged with a pdf template to create a pdf document. What is happening now is that the pdf is being merged before the xml file is exported. I'm trying to solve the problem by using .when (GenerateData)/.then(CreatePDF) and it seems to work for the main functions (GenerateData and CreatePDF) but if I add a success callback to GenerateData, CreatePDF executes before the success callback finishes.

Should the callback handlers also get deferred and if so how should they be coded ? I haven't found a concrete example online...

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You can use a deferred object

```
var myAsyncPromise = new $.Deferred(); //resolved when the xml is done

var promise = $.ajax({}); //some ajax call

var createXml = function () {

    //when this code is run and complete do this
    myAsyncPromise.resolve();
} 
var complete =  $.when(promise, myAsyncPromise);


complete.done(function (data){
      //when both async actions are done this code will run
});
```

If you have two async functions that you need to wait for in order to run your code this is one way of doing it.